# Showing that a certain series diverges

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am trying to show that
$$h(n)=\sum_{km=n}\frac{(-1)^{k+m}}{(\log(2k)\log(2m))^{2}}$$
is not bounded and I set $n=2^{r}$.
I then obtain the following: $$h(2^{r})=\sum_{km=2^{r}}\frac{(-1)^{k+m}}{(\log(2k)\log(2m))^{2}}=\frac{(-2)}{\log(2^{r+1})\log(2)}+\sum_{\substack{km=2^{r}\\
k,m\neq 1}}\frac{1}{(\log(2k)\log(2m))^{2}}$$
$$=\frac{(-2)}{\log(2^{r+1})\log(2)}+\sum_{m=2}^{r-1}\frac{1}{(\log(2\cdot 2^{m})\log(2\cdot 2^{r-m}))^{2}}=\frac{(-2)}{\log(2^{r+1})\log(2)}+\sum_{m=2}^{r-1}\frac{1}{(\log( 2^{m+1})\log(2^{r-m+1}))^{2}}$$
$$\lim_{r\to \infty}h(2^{r})=\lim_{r\to \infty}\frac{(-2)}{\log(2^{r+1})\log(2)}+\sum_{m=2}^{r-1}\frac{1}{(\log( 2^{m+1})\log(2^{r-m+1}))^{2}}=\lim_{r\to \infty}\sum_{m=2}^{r-1}\frac{1}{(\log( 2^{m+1})\log(2^{r-m+1}))^{2}}$$
$$=\lim_{r\to \infty}\sum_{m=2}^{r-1}\frac{1}{(m+1)^{2}(r-m+1)^{2}(\log^{4}( 2))}=\frac{1}{\log^{4}(2)}\lim_{r\to \infty}\sum_{m=2}^{r-1}\frac{1}{(m+1)^{2}(r-m+1)^{2}}$$

However, I am not sure how to determine how the last item behaves. In fact, it seems like it should converge by comparison. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand how the summation is varying. $km=n$ is there typo?

Comment: The sum is over the divisors of $n$. The reason I choose $n=2^{r}$ is to make the sum nicer since we only have divisors of the form $2^{k}$.

Comment: I agree that this last expression seems bounded (by $\sum_{m=2}^\infty \frac1{(m+1)^2}$ for example). I recommend trying a similar thing with $h(6^r)$ or $h(30^r)$: still concrete examples that can be worked out explictly, and still with most divisors even, but now with many more divisors.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the formula you obtained for $n = 2^r$ can't be correct, because when $r = 2$, we have the divisors $k , m \in \{1, 2, 4\}$, hence
$$h(2^2) = 2 \frac{(-1)^{1+4}}{\log^2 2 \log^2 8} + \frac{(-1)^{2+2}}{\log^4 4} \approx -0.691932 < 0,$$ whereas your formula always yields a positive number.  So there is a computational error somewhere, but I haven't taken the time to review it in detail.

Second, numerical computation for $n \le 5000$ vaguely suggests that the sequence $\{h(n)\}_{n \ge 1}$ may be bounded:

[image]

The behavior seems to be convergent toward zero:  I obtain $h(2^{1000}) \approx -2.97826 \times 10^{-6}$, for instance, and a plot of $h(2^r)$ for $r \le 1000$ looks like this:
[image]

So I do not believe a strategy of choosing $n = 2^r$ will be successful.  Instead, I think that in order to develop an appropriate upper bound, we would want to choose $n$ such that it is the product of distinct odd primes; i.e., half a primorial:  $$n = \frac{p_m\#}{2} = \prod_{k=2}^m p_k$$ where $p_k$ is the $k^{\rm th}$ prime.  Again, numeric computation yields for $2 \le m \le 20$ the following plot:
[image]

Now this is where things start looking spicy.  The sequence appears to be *increasing*.  Note that for $m = 20$, $n \approx 2.7897 \times 10^{26}$, so this is not a small number, but it is certainly suggestive that such a strategy could show that $h$ is not bounded above.  However, such computations might be in error (we are dealing with a very large number of terms that are very small), and the computational expense grows rapidly for larger values of $m$, so I can't provide further insight at this time.